# Can't edit comment with broken link

Tags: discussion, comments

I've commented on an answer in 2015 [Make my password protected SSH key expire or timeout after a while](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118223/make-my-password-protected-ssh-key-expire-or-timeout-after-a-while#comment252638_118624)

The link is broken, I wanted to fix it. I've commented again, but since my comment got an upvote, I think it might hide the correction to my earlier comment.

Is this the way it should work? My comment is less useful now, but I don't want to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to edit comments after the 5 minute grace period (unless you are a moderator).

Since the comment has just gained one single upvote, I wouldn't think too long and remove it since it isn't useful any more.

Just post a new comment, or if it is really really useful, you could add it to the answer. If that is allowed depends how a community stands regarding editing someone else's answers and how useful and related it is to the answer.